# How can I compile my smart contract from an API using solc?

Tags: solidity, web3js, solc, abi, bytecode

I want to compile my solidity code (smart contract) inside my node.js API using the solc library to get the ABI and bytecode of my solidity.

What I want in details is an input that can read solidity code "just like a text"
from a file. I want to be able to compile multiple smart contracts.

Can anyone provide me with an example?

## solc #nodejs #solidity #javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc) and [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js)

```
var solc = require('solc')
var input = 'contract x { function g() {} }'
// Setting 1 as second parameter activates the optimiser
var optimize = 1
var output = solc.compile(input, optimize)
for (var contractName in output.contracts) {
    // code and ABI that are needed by web3
    console.log(contractName + ': ' + output.contracts[contractName].bytecode)
    console.log(contractName + '; ' + JSON.parse(output.contracts[contractName].interface)
}
```

you can read the content of the contract from a file also:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var input = fs.readFileSync('<file path here>', 'utf8');
// rest of the code
```

If you have any specific question post your code

Comment: Thanks but what I want is the input that can read the solidity code from a file. I want to create an input for solidity code so I can compile multiple smart contracts.

Comment: read ny updated answer, just use `fs` (base Node.js module) to read the file