# Is there an api that compiles solidity contracts?

Tags: solidity, compilation, frontend, api

I have a static webpage and it should remain static. In this website a user generates solidity files. I would like to compile them by sending the uncompiled solidity via an api to a compiler and then receive either the compiled bytecode (potentially with warnings) or receiving an error-message if the compilation was not successful.

I do not think that I can use `solc`, as [this article](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49246/how-can-i-compile-my-smart-contract-from-an-api-using-solc) suggests, because I have a strict frontend usecase.

For instance I know that etherscan has an api that lets you verify contracts and within that verification there is of course a compilation, but there is no way to just get solidity files compiled. I know that remix.ethereum is all about compiling solidity and there seem to be some javascript libraries that do interact with it, but to my knowledge there is no (hacky or not hacky way) of sending programming code and receiving compiled code. Lastly, I could of course set up my own server and do the thing, but I'd rather not, unless there really is no other solution.

Comment: If by "API" you mean like a REST API, not I don't think you'll find one. You can however use [solc-js](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js), which is a javascript wrapper for solc. It is usable within the browser and includes examples in the README for doing just that

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant REST API. But I cannot use solc-js because it requires 'fs', which only works for nodejs if I understand correctly. At least it gives me this error message. ```Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myname/Projects/VotingRegistry/voting-contracts-frontend/node_modules/solc´´´.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no public API that directly allows you to send uncompiled Solidity code and receive the compiled bytecode. However, you could consider setting up your own server to compile the code.

Comment: Thanks  @AmariS1, I'll wait to see if others might know about an API. I mean the funny thing is that it exists within the etherscan-api, but one cannot use it just by itself. It would be simple to actually expose an api just for the compilation.

Comment: yes but actually i might have found something i am Alchemy univ student and they have this service which provides an API for compiling, deploying, and interacting with Ethereum contracts. You can use Alchemy's API to send your uncompiled Solidity code and receive the compiled bytecode or an error message. Give it a try it might be something you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks @AmariS1, that's cool. Couldn't find the API though, do you have a link? At least on a first glance I didn't see any compilation api on their docs https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/api-overview

Comment: You can go through this link [https://docs.alchemyapi.io/](https://docs.alchemyapi.io/) This is the link to Alchemy API documentation

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see any endpoints for contract compilation. Maybe you can point me to the section in the docs where it is described how one creates a request to have solidity contracts  compiled.

Comment: I apologies but I also am not able to find the proper function for the direct  endpoint for compilation and Only near to that i could find was the [Solc-Js](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) it also does not have the direct end point but it does allow you to compile code on client-side and the `fs` cannot be used in the browser environment.
I have found this [OpenEthereum-JSON-API](https://openethereum.github.io/wiki/JSON-RPC) it has the functionality where we can compile the code on remote server I will myself try this and you might also want to try it.